# How to customize product category widget in woocommerce

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

i can not understand How to customize product category widget in woocommerce Version 3.0.7 (not using any plugin).
like that..
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can customize the arguments of product category widget by following code in functions.php,

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', 'widget_arguments' );

function widget_arguments( $args ) {

$args['exclude'] = array('12','14');

return $args;
}
```

Here is the argument list from default file.

http://hookr.io/plugins/woocommerce/3.0.6/files/includes-widgets-class-wc-widget-product-categories/

Comment: how to design CSS part in this page.?

Comment: extend this class : WC_Widget_Product_Categories to change the design

Comment: how to divide category or subcategoty in this code.  wp_list_categories( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_categories_widget_args', $list_args ) );